# Pressing android menu button in Appium

Tags: testing, webdriver, appium, remotewebdriver

I run my test using Appium with `RemoteWebDriver`.

I try to press Android Menu button with the following java code:

```java
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("keycode", Integer.toString(AndroidKeyCode.MENU));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("mobile: keyevent", AndroidKeyCode.MENU);
```

Which returns me "Not yet implemented" error. Is there any way to press menu button? Please note I use `RemoteWebDriver` not `AndroidDriver`. Unfortunately `RemoteWebDriver` can not be cast to `AndroidDriver`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use AppiumDriver instead of RemoteWebDriver.

```java
new AppiumDriver(new URL("hubURL"),capabilities);
```

And send key event

```java
AppiumDriver.sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.MENU)
```